# How can I pass a type or variable to this is_same function?

Tags: c++, templates

I want to be able to pass a type or variable to a function that will return true or false if it's the same type:

```
template <typename T>
struct OneType
{
    template <typename U> //???
    static constexpr bool is_same_type(U u = std::declval<U>()) { return std::is_same_v<T, U>; }
};

struct AnotherType
{
    AnotherType() = delete;
    AnotherType(int a) {}
};

void main()
{
    OneType<int> a;

    a.is_same_type<int>(); // CAN BE CALLED WITH A TYPE
    
    int anInt;
    a.is_same_type(anInt); // CAN BE CALLED WITH A VARIABLE

    
    AnotherType anotherType(7);
    a.is_same_type<AnotherType>(); // CAN THESE BE MADE TO WORK?
    a.is_same_type(anotherType); 

}
```

Comment: OT: `void main()` is illegal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default value is unnecessary, just define:

```
template <typename U>
static constexpr bool is_same_type() { return std::is_same_v<T, U>; }
```

Then use it with parenthesis:

```
a.is_same_type<AnotherType>();
```

If the type of an object is needed then [`decltype`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) can be used:

```
AnotherType obj;
a.is_same_type<decltype(obj)>();
```

Comment: But how do I call it with an object? AnotherType obj; a.is_same_type(obj); I can have two different functions, one that takes at argument and one that takes none.

Comment: `a.is_same_type<decltype(obj)>();` modified the answer.

Comment: Alternatively, you can add an overload where you pass the argument by reference: https://godbolt.org/z/94WT3Y.